# As for generalized eigenspaces, do these results still hold on infinite-dimensional spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose V is a vector space and $T\in L(V)$.
Let $G(\lambda,T) $ denote the generalized eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda $.

In other words, $G(\lambda,T)=\{\;v\in V\;\vert\;{(T-\lambda I)}^{\;k}\;v=0\;\;for\;some\;integer\;k>0\;\}$.

If V is finite-dimensional, we konw that $ G(\lambda,T)=null\;{(T-\lambda I)}^{dim\;V} $. So we have:

(a)$\quad$ $G(\lambda,T) $ is a subspace of $V$;

(b)$\quad$ $G(\lambda,T) $ is invariant under $ T $;

(c)$\quad$ $G(\lambda,T) $ is invariant under $ T-\lambda I $;

(d)$\quad$ $ (T-\lambda I)\;\vert_{G(\lambda,T)} $ is nilpotent.

If V is infinite-dimensional, do the results above still hold? $\ $Thanks!

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimensional, how do you define the generalized eigenspace?

Comment: @Mindlack Generally, $G(\lambda,T)=\{\;v\in V\;\vert\;{(T-\lambda I)}^{\;k}\;v=0\;\;for\;some\;integer\;k>0\;\}$.

Comment: Then $G(\lambda,T)$ is the reunion of the nondecreasing sequence of subspaces $V_n=\ker{(T-\lambda I)^n}$. Each $V_n$ is a subspace stable under $T$ thus so is $G(\lambda,T)$. If $(T-\lambda I)x \in V_n$, then $x \in V_{n+1}$, thus $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}G(\lambda,T)=G(\lambda,T)$. So a,b,c) still hold. However, d) may not hold (ie it’s possible that $V_n$ is strictly increasing, eg $V=R[x]$, $T$ is the derivation, and $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for your answer! Although I don't fully understand, I believe you are right.